# how to collapse whitespaces in a region?

Tags: emacs, whitespace

Let's say I have this tabulated text file:

```
field1        variable_length_field    variable_length_field
aaaaaa        aaaa                     aaaaaaaaa
bbbbbb        bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb     bbbb
```

How can I transform it to:

```
field1 variable_length_field variable_length_field
aaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaa
bbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbb
```

I know I could use `replace-regexp` on the region, but Emacs regexps don't come naturally. I was looking for something like `delete-whitespace-rectangle`, but that does not do what I expect, or I am misusing it. Having the ability to do this per-column would be desirable too, i.e:

```
field1        variable_length_field variable_length_field
aaaaaa        aaaa aaaaaaaaa
bbbbbb        bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbb
```

Comment: Where does the _rectangle_ come into this?

Comment: There are two rectangles there that could be collapsed down to one column each, but finding them requires scanning -- assuming that the data fields are not of fixed width.

Comment: You mention that the file is "tabulated," which I take to mean not that the separating whitespace is tab characters, but rather that the fields are left-aligned. Is it the case that none of the fields can contain whitespace?

Comment: I still don't see the connection with "rectangles" -- it looks like a line-by-line `s/[ \t]+/ /g` replacement would do the job just fine. (If only I knew enough Emacs to give the keys to hit...)

Comment: @seh what I want to mean is "like a table".

Comment: @sarnold: I want to be able to do this with rectangles in the case that I want to keep some of the whitespace in some columns. If I wanted to do it to all columns then yes I could just simply use a "normal" region.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This function should do the trick:

```
(defun just-one-space-in-region (beg end)
  "replace all whitespace in the region with single spaces"
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region beg end)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "\\s-+" nil t)
        (replace-match " ")))))
```

And, since the question was updated to apply to spaces in a rectangle, try this:

```
(require 'rect)  
(defun just-one-space-in-rect-line (start end)
  (save-restriction
    (save-match-data
      (narrow-to-region (+ (point) start)
                        (+ (point) end))
      (while (re-search-forward "\\s-+" nil t)
        (replace-match " ")))))
(defun just-one-space-in-rect (start end)
  "replace all whitespace in the rectangle with single spaces"
  (interactive "r")
  (apply-on-rectangle 'just-one-space-in-rect-line start end))
```

Comment: That's almost perfect. This works for a whole region but not rectangles, clarified question.

Comment: second version is perfect! I was trying to learn how to use rectangles in elisp yesterday to solve this but couldn't get it right. This is a great example to learn from. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Not really answering your question but there is

```
 M-SPC runs the command just-one-space, which is an interactive
 compiled Lisp function in `simple.el'.

 It is bound to M-SPC.

 (just-one-space &optional N)

 Delete all spaces and tabs around point, leaving one space (or N spaces).

 [back]
```

which is useful when you want to delete whitespace in one off cases.  It might be suitable for a macro case where the deletions are at random lines with no fixed pattern.

Answer (score 4):

You can deal with your rectangle requirements using cua-mode's rectangle editing facilities*.

1. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `cua-selection-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> or `(cua-selection-mode 1)`
   (myself, I have this enabled permanently).
2. Mark the rectangle within which you wish to collapse the whitespace, using <kbd>C-RET</kbd> and the normal movement keys.
3. Call `cua-replace-in-rectangle`:
   <kbd>M-r</kbd> `\s-+` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>SPC</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>
4. <kbd>C-RET</kbd> again to end rectangle editing.

(*) This won't work if you need fields to the right of the rectangle to remain aligned, as in that case you would need to insert new spaces to compensate for the ones which were removed. You could use `2C-split` and `2C-merge` or just kill/yank the right-most rectangle to work around that.

Comment: I just arrived to this answer. Would you mind explaining why `\s-+` matches any number of spaces? I understand that `\s` is a space, and that `+` means one or more, but why the `-` sign?

Comment: No, `\s` doesn't mean a space (n.b. not all regex languages are the same!). In Emacs, `\s` means a character of the *syntax* indicated by the next character. The `-` code is for the whitespace syntax class. You can also use a space instead of a hyphen, but the hyphen is more readable. See `C-h i g (elisp) Regexp Backslash RET` and then search in the page for `\sCODE`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an IDE? If you're using something like Eclipse, then you could format whitespace options within it. (In Eclipse, press CTRL+3 and search for 'formatter'. I apologize for not remembering the exact path!) Then, you should be able to highlight everything and press ctrl+shift+G to auto=format everything.

Let us know if it helps! (Or, if you'd like to spinup code that will do this, let us know the language.)

Comment: "Emacs" is listed in both the tags _and_ body of the question. :)

Comment: Sorry about that, still new! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `cua-selection-mode` you can use `rectangle-mark-mode` or the mouse to select a rectangle and then do the white space replacement.

Short version:

<kbd>C-x</kbd>  <kbd>SPC</kbd> to select the region, then <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> `\s-+` <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>SPC</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd>

Will replace all contiguous instances of whitespace with a single space within the specified rectangle

---

Long Version:

1. Select the region you want to edit

   - You can hold down <kbd>C-M</kbd> and then click and drag with <kbd>mouse-1</kbd> to select a rectangle. (Doesn't work on my emacs version but is mentioned in the [official docs.](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html))
   - Or put the point where you want the rectangle to start, hit <kbd>C-x</kbd>  <kbd>SPC</kbd> to enter `rectangle-mark-mode` and then move the cursor so that the region you want is highlighted
2. Remove excess whitespace using `replace-regexp`

   - Hit <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> to activate `replace-regexp`, it should now prompt you for the pattern you want to search for
   - Enter `\s-+` as the search pattern, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (matches one or more white space characters)
   - Enter what you want to replace the white space with, in this case you can just use a space by hitting <kbd>SPC</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Perform the replacement

   - Now all of the whitespace to be replaced should be highlighted
   - Hit <kbd>!</kbd> to replace them all at once
   - Or you can replace them one-by-one by hitting <kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>SPC</kbd> for each one