# how to delete non ascii characters in emacs

Tags: unicode, emacs, character

I am really new to elisp programming and I am trying to write an Emacs elisp function to delete all non ASCII characters in a highlighted region.  I found a sample elisp function of how to find a non ASCII character here:  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FindingNonAsciiCharacters.  I tried to modify it myself but couldn't get it to work.  Can somebody show me how to modify the following elisp function to delete all non ASCII characters in a highlighted region in GNU Emacs:

```
(defun find-first-non-ascii-char ()
  "Find the first non-ascii character from point onwards."
  (interactive)
  (let (point)
    (save-excursion
      (setq point
            (catch 'non-ascii
              (while (not (eobp))
                (or (eq (char-charset (following-char))
                        'ascii)
                    (throw 'non-ascii (point)))
                (forward-char 1)))))
    (if point
        (goto-char point)
        (message "No non-ascii characters."))))
```

Answer (score 5):

I think I found an answer by modifying the answer to this post: [how to collapse whitespaces in a region?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674912/how-to-collapse-whitespaces-in-a-region)

Here is what I came up with:

```
(defun del-binary_characters (beg end)
  "Delete binary characters in a region"
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region beg end)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "[^[:ascii:]]" nil t)
        (replace-match "")))))
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but to just find non-ASCII characters interactively you can do this:

```
M-x search-forward-regexp
[^[:ascii:]]
```